# select from mysql where 2 cels is same

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this table:

```
table_id | table_who | table_to | table_text
1        | 2         | 1        | "sometext"
2        | 1         | 2        | "sometext"
3        | 1         | 2        | "sometext"
4        | 4         | 1        | "sometext"
5        | 5         | 2        | "sometext"
6        | 2         | 2        | "sometext"
```

I want to select all rows where table_who or table_to is "2". Can you help me, please? i'm verry noob in php and mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE table_who = 2 OR table_to = 2`

Comment: start with the mysqli_* or pdo interfaces when you do, not the deprecated mysql_* functions

Answer (score 1):

Use a `OR` condition in your `WHERE` clause like

```
WHERE 2 in (table_who , table_to);
```

(OR)

```
WHERE table_who = 2 OR table_to = 2;
```

Per your edit in post, use a `IN` operator and include those conditions

`where table_who in (1,2) and table_to in (1,2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$qry="select * from tableName where (table_who=2 or table_to=2)";
$result=mysqli_query($qry);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['table_text'];
}
```

Simple select from data base.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this query :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE table_who = 2 OR table_to = 2';
```

Comment: That's got a syntax error in it which is going to cause a fatal error

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers, but is show me even other records.

i want to show, for example for value 2 and 1, just table_id 1,2,3,6

look an schema:

```
table_who | table_to<br/>
1 | 1 (possible case)<br/>
1 | 2 (possible case)<br/>
2 | 2 (possible case)<br/>
2 | 1 (possible case)<br/>
```

just this records i wanna see on results for 1 and 2, not all.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not 5, and don't post amendments to your question as answers. Instead edit your question.

Comment: If you have a question then edit your post and include it there. Don't post it as answer.

Comment: use a `IN` operator like `where table_who I (1,2) or table_to in (1,2)`

Comment: @Rahul: the OR needs to be AND

Comment: @PaulF, absolutely, not sure how missed it. Thanks man. Can't edit the comment and so edited my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use the OR-Operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_who = 2 OR table_to = 2;
```